# how to compare a dataset to a subset of it self? [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, compare, pandas-groupby

I am trying to automate and built a cleaner code.
I want my code to get a CSV, group it by X (currently variable named "Class")
and then remove every 3std from mean.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


my_path = "data_291018.csv"
data_loc = pd.read_csv(my_path)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_loc)
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed', case=False)], axis=1)

class_8 = df[df["Class"] == 8]
class_11 = df[df["Class"] == 11]

heads = df.columns[4:].values

for i in heads:
    class_8[i] = class_8[i].apply(lambda x: x if abs(x-class_8[i].mean()) < 3*class_8[i].std() else np.nan)
    class_11[i] = class_11[i].apply(lambda x: x if abs(x-class_11[i].mean()) < 3*class_11[i].std() else np.nan)

both = pd.concat([class_8, class_11])

both.to_csv("data.csv", sep=',')
```

I tried instead of running on two different DFs adding

```
new_df = df.copy()
class_df = df.groupby("Class")
```

and running

```
for i in heads:
    new_df[i] = new_df[i].apply(lambda x: x if abs(x-class_df[i].mean()) < 3*class_df[i].std() else np.nan)
```

and it failed...
"raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: ('Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects', u'occurred at index SubjNum')"

Can you please help me?
In later stages I want to group by more than 1 variable.

Thank you so much!

**DF looks something like this:**

```
SubjNum Class   Genderm1f2  LRLevel exp1    exp2    exp3    exp4    exp5

8001    8   1   1   88  2   15  19  92

8002    8   2   1   85  59  19  20  97

8003    8   2   1   84  52  12  18  91

8004    11  2   1   85  44  17  20  92

8005    11  2   1   81  35  400 18  93

8006    11  1   1   190 56  20  17  97
```

I want to remove cells that exceeds 3 std from mean based on class/gender etc.

```
SubjNum Class   Genderm1f2  LRLevel exp1    exp2    exp3    exp4    exp5

8001    8   1   1   88  . 15    19  92

8002    8   2   1   85  59  19  20  97

8003    8   2   1   84  52  12  18  91

8004    11  2   1   85  44  17  20  92

8005    11  2   1   81  35  . 18    93

8006    11  1   1   .   56  20  17  97
```

Comment: you mean subset of supset? if you can provide  few lines of the dataframe and desired output.

Comment: hi @pygo thanks for the replay -  subset. I will edit the my question

Comment: what does it mean `I want to remove cells that exceeds 3 std from mean based on class/gender etc.`

Comment: If a cell value exceeds 3 std from the columns mean I want to replace it with numpy.nan @pygo

Comment: @ Nachshon Korem , i have just placed some thought on the question in the answer section as those can not be placed on the comment section so see if it helps otherwise i'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As much i could understood, i'm just placing my observation here so you may have a look if its relevant what you are looking for, However perfect answer still awaited from Experts:

Simulation dataFrame from your example:

```
>>> df
   SubjNum  Class  Genderm1f2  LRLevel  exp1  exp2  exp3  exp4  exp5
0     8001      8           1        1    88     2    15    19    92
1     8002      8           2        1    85    59    19    20    97
2     8003      8           2        1    84    52    12    18    91
3     8004     11           2        1    85    44    17    20    92
4     8005     11           2        1    81    35   400    18    93
5     8006     11           1        1   190    56    20    17    97
```

Mean based on these two columns:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Class', 'Genderm1f2']).mean()
                  SubjNum  LRLevel   exp1  exp2   exp3  exp4  exp5
Class Genderm1f2
8     1            8001.0      1.0   88.0   2.0   15.0  19.0  92.0
      2            8002.5      1.0   84.5  55.5   15.5  19.0  94.0
11    1            8006.0      1.0  190.0  56.0   20.0  17.0  97.0
      2            8004.5      1.0   83.0  39.5  208.5  19.0  92.5
```

standard deviation base on these two columns:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Class', 'Genderm1f2']).std()
                   SubjNum  LRLevel      exp1      exp2        exp3      exp4      exp5
Class Genderm1f2
8     1                NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN
      2           0.707107      0.0  0.707107  4.949747    4.949747  1.414214  4.242641
11    1                NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN
      2           0.707107      0.0  2.828427  6.363961  270.821897  1.414214  0.707107
```

Just a groupby the two desired columns with a aggregate `mean()` & `std()`.

```
>>> df.groupby(['Class', 'Genderm1f2']).agg(['mean','std'])
                 SubjNum           LRLevel        exp1            exp2             exp3             exp4            exp5
                    mean       std    mean  std   mean       std  mean       std   mean         std mean       std  mean       std
Class Genderm1f2
8     1           8001.0       NaN       1  NaN   88.0       NaN   2.0       NaN   15.0         NaN   19       NaN  92.0       NaN
      2           8002.5  0.707107       1  0.0   84.5  0.707107  55.5  4.949747   15.5    4.949747   19  1.414214  94.0  4.242641
11    1           8006.0       NaN       1  NaN  190.0       NaN  56.0       NaN   20.0         NaN   17       NaN  97.0       NaN
      2           8004.5  0.707107       1  0.0   83.0  2.828427  39.5  6.363961  208.5  270.821897   19  1.414214  92.5  0.707107
```

Just a groupby the two desired columns with a aggregate `mean()` & `std()` whos values is greater then 3 .

```
>>> df.groupby(['Class', 'Genderm1f2']).agg(['mean','std']) > 3
                 SubjNum        LRLevel         exp1          exp2         exp3         exp4         exp5
                    mean    std    mean    std  mean    std   mean    std  mean    std  mean    std  mean    std
Class Genderm1f2
8     1             True  False   False  False  True  False  False  False  True  False  True  False  True  False
      2             True  False   False  False  True  False   True   True  True   True  True  False  True   True
11    1             True  False   False  False  True  False   True  False  True  False  True  False  True  False
      2             True  False   False  False  True  False   True   True  True   True  True  False  True  False
```

Comment: Please don't place downvote on this  as this is Just a heads answer based on the  understand and just to Facilitate the understanding  on the dataset provided, will remove it if it does not looks relevant to the OP.

Comment: Hi @pygo, I want to export to csv much larger datasets.I want to extract a mean and STD for each group-by element and remove spesific cells that exceeds # STDs. the exported file should look like the imported file, winth STDs remove.

Comment: Pls see if  [this link](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/) if it helps..

Comment: I know it should, but I am having troubles extrapolating from this to my question. I want to run the algorithm on the original data, but calculate deviations from the grouped norm